# How can I sum values over a range of dates in Numbers?

Tags: numbers

I have the following formula

> ```
> SUMIFS(Daily Log::Income,Daily Log::A,"≥"&A3,Daily Log::A,"<"&A4)
> ```

that I want to sum income over the associated month.  As you can see, it's not doing what I am expecting it to—how can I effect what I need?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works by dereferencing the value of a cell directly to the condition

Example:

```
SUMIFS(Daily Log::Income,Daily Log::A,">=2014-07-01",Daily Log::A,"<2014-08-01")
```

Referencing the cell could also be made possible with the same construct; by adding ampersand followed by the cell name outside the double quotes.

Example:

```
SUMIFS(Daily Log::Income,Daily Log::A,">="&A3,Daily Log::A,"<"&A4)
```

Comment: Thanks; this didn't *exactly* answer the question, but it led me to it! Numbers doesn't understand the Unicode `≥` that I used; replacing it with the `>=` composite fixed the issue :)  If you edit to include this information, I'd be more than happy to give you the tick.  (And welcome to Apple.SE!)